Using PACKET_SANOUT-HASH, data packets connected to the same thread are not distributed to the same thread
Using a packet socket to retrieve data from the network card, a fanout group was created using the PACKET-FANOUT-HASH fanout type of fanout, consisting of four threads. The data packet with only one clean HTTP connection was played back to the network card, and the program output showed that the data was not processed by the same thread
const int NUM_THREADS = 4;  // 线程数量
const char* INTERFACE_NAME = "dummy0";  // 网卡接口名

void receivePackets(int thread_id) {
    int sockfd;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct sockaddr_ll sa;
    uint32_t fanout_option;
    int cluster_id = 7223;  // 每个线程可以使用不同的 cluster_id

    // 创建原始套接字
    sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Thread " << thread_id << ": Socket creation failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // 配置网卡接口
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, INTERFACE_NAME, IFNAMSIZ);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Thread " << thread_id << ": ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return;
    }

    // 绑定套接字到接口
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sa.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa)) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Thread " << thread_id << ": Socket bind failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return;
    }   

    // 设置 fanout 选项
    fanout_option = (PACKET_FANOUT_HASH | PACKET_FANOUT_FLAG_DEFRAG) << 16 | cluster_id;
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_FANOUT, &fanout_option, sizeof(fanout_option)) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Thread " << thread_id << ": setsockopt(PACKET_FANOUT) failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "Thread " << thread_id << ": Successfully configured PACKET_FANOUT with HASH and DEFRAG." << std::endl;

    unsigned char buffer[65536];
    while (true) {
        ssize_t len = recv(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (len < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Thread " << thread_id << ": recv failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            close(sockfd);
            return;
        }

        // 添加更多调试信息
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = now - std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Thread " << thread_id << ": Received packet of length: " << len 
                << " at " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;

        // 这里可以进一步处理数据包
    }

    close(sockfd);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    // // 启动线程
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back(receivePackets, i);
        usleep(1000 * 100);
    }

    // 等待线程完成
    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 0;
}


The output of the program is as follows
Thread 0: Successfully configured PACKET_FANOUT with HASH and DEFRAG.
Thread 1: Successfully configured PACKET_FANOUT with HASH and DEFRAG.
Thread 2: Successfully configured PACKET_FANOUT with HASH and DEFRAG.
Thread 3: Successfully configured PACKET_FANOUT with HASH and DEFRAG.
Thread 1: Received packet of length: 82 at -6.01e-07 seconds.
Thread 1: Received packet of length: 78 at -6.6e-08 seconds.
Thread 3: Received packet of length: 70 at -6.6e-08 seconds.
Thread 2: Received packet of length: 326 at -5.5e-08 seconds.
Thread 3: Received packet of length: 70 at -1.51e-07 seconds.
Thread 3: Received packet of length: 70 at -1.06e-07 seconds.
Thread 1: Received packet of length: 1765 at -1.1e-07 seconds.
Thread 3: Received packet of length: 70 at -6.2e-08 seconds.
Thread 1: Received packet of length: 440 at -2.4e-08 seconds.
Thread 3: Received packet of length: 70 at -5.4e-08 seconds.
Thread 3: Received packet of length: 70 at -2.3e-08 seconds.
Thread 3: Received packet of length: 70 at -2.4e-08 seconds.


Shouldn't the expected output be processed in the same thread？

Most likely reason is with raw socket the packets are read directly from the device driver therefore bypasses the FANOUT logic which likely to be implemented at the socket_ops level. Try to use SOCK_STREAM to see if it changes the behavior where you have to use accept() to handle a request, I think that is the intended use case for FANOUT logic.

Only a small number of packets will experience this situation, and the majority of packets are read by the same thread

My Ubuntu uses a 5.4 kernel, but switching to a 5.10 kernel eliminates this situation. Has the kernel been repaired and is there any relevant information?

The obvious way to know about it is to look into the source code changes. You can find the exact version where the issue has been fixed between 5.4 to 5.10 then look into the git log search for FANOUT related commits.
